# How to set weekends as working days and still have them highlighted a different colour Microsoft project 2010

Tags: ms-project

The title says it all really,

I'm trying to create a program where the weekends are working day however we still want to see when the weekends are so having them shaded/a different colour would be helpful.

is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you're in a `Gantt` or `Team Planner` view, open the `Timescale` editor**, select the `Non-working time` tab and choose in the `Calendar` drop-down a calendar that has weekends set as non working time.

I'd wager that you edited the `Standard (Project Calendar)` to make weekends workable; if that's the case, a new calendar will need to be created that keeps weekends set to non-working time. This new calendar is what you would set your `Timescale` > `Non-working Time` to display.

**right-click the top area of the Gantt chart where the dates are, click Timescale